# jQuery limit maximum amount of checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, max

I have 3 check-boxes with `name="ItemGrp1"` and 4 check-boxes with `name="ItemGrp2"`.

Only 1 box can be checked from `ItemGrp1` and only 2 maximum from `ItemGrp2`. A total of maximum 3 check-boxes can be checked.

I need to stop the user from ticking check-boxes if the user ticks more than total 3 check-boxes and also stop if user checks more than 1 from `ItemGrp1` and more than 2 from `ItemGrp2`.

The names `ItemGrp1`/`ItemGrp2` mentioned here are retrieved from a database and can be variable, so they should not be selected directly by name in jQuery.

My current HTML:

```
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="10" />
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="20" />
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="30" />

<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="40" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="50" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="60" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="70" />
```

And in Javascript:

```
var val_arr = [];

$("input[name^=ItemGrp]").change(function () {

    var CBVal = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if (val_arr[CBVal] != 'A') {
            val_arr[CBVal] = 'A';
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying to use an array, then check if a checkbox is checked , if yes, then set the index to the checkbox value and value of that index to 'A', and then check the total count of the array. But the problem is that the length of the array comes out to be erroneous.

Comment: also if you have `ItemGrp3` and `ItemGrp3` how is the selection rules

Comment: if you don't know the names, it will be hard to limit. Think you need to post some code you tried and a little bit more about how your DB gets them and what's possible to know up front.

Comment: @Will : please check the update section

Comment: Where's `val_arr` defined?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DFD2d/1/

Comment: What defines the number of allowable checkboxes per group? Can `ItemGrp3` have up to three checked, `ItemGrp4` up to four etc.?

Comment: @j08691 : it would be set manually , as couldn't find any way to read it from database and generate dynamic javascript variables for limiting the checkbox selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom `data-max` attribute on each input field, which is filled through the database:

```
<input 
   name="<?php echo $field["name"]; ?>" 
   type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $field["value"]; ?>" 
   data-max="<?php echo $field["max_checked"]; ?>" 
/>
```

Then you can use the following checks in your javascript event handler:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {

  var InputName = $(this).attr("name");
  var MaxAllowed = $(this).attr("data-max");

   // Get amount of checked boxes with the same name
   if( $("input[name=" + InputName  + "]:checked").length >= MaxAllowed ){

       // Disable the remaining checkboxes of the same name
       $("input[name=" + InputName  + "]").not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");

   } else {

       // Enable the inputs again when he unchecks one
       $("input[name=" + InputName  + "]").removeAttr("disabled");

});
```

Comment: but how to limit selection in each category/group, like only 1 could be checked from ItemGrp1 & only 3 from ItemGrp2...

Comment: Well how do you save the "maximum amount of checked" per group? How is  javascript supposed to access this?

Comment: right now i am doing it manually,  i have set if grp1 selection.length > 1 show error, if grp2 selection.length >3 show error ......... but would prefer reading the limit from database and use it in javascript

Comment: Then you need to think how you will pass this value to javascript. You could for example add a `data-max` attribute to each input field, which javascript can then read.

Comment: ok suppose i have added data-max = 1 for ItemGrp1 and data-max = 3 for ItemGrp2 , now what to do further?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49768/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-dark-ashelin)

Comment: As a final note: I added another check to enable the checkboxes again when the user unticks one, so he has the chance to choose another option.

Answer (score 2):

Separate the inputs with a div

```
<div class="grp1_div">
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="10" />
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="20" />
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="30" />
</div>
<div class="grp1_div">
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="40" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="50" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="60" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="70" />
</div>
```

then you can call

```
$(".grp1_div input:checked").length


$(".grp2_div input:checked").length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SMCR8/

Use the new `.prop()` function:

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
```

JS :

```
var limititem1 = 1;
var limititem2 = 2;
var val_arr = [];



$("input[name^=ItemGrp]").change(function () {


  //dont check if total reached
if( $("input[name^=ItemGrp]:checked").length > ( limititem1+limititem2))
 {
     $(this).prop('checked', false);   
 }else
 //dont check if (ItemGrp1) and max reached
if( $(this).attr('name') == 'ItemGrp1' && $("input[name^=ItemGrp1]:checked").length > limititem1)
{
   $(this).prop('checked', false);      
}else
//dont check if ( ItemGrp2) and max reached
if ( $(this).attr('name') == 'ItemGrp2' && $("input[name^=ItemGrp2]:checked").length > limititem2)
{
   $(this).prop('checked', false);      
}else
//free to go 
{


    var CBVal = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        if (val_arr[CBVal] != 'A') {
            val_arr[CBVal] = 'A';
        }
    }
}
});
```

HTML :

```
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="10" />
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="20" />
<input name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="30" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="40" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="50" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="60" />
<input name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="70" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [this here](http://jsfiddle.net/49bQ2/)?

You can extend the conditions and limits with minimal changes in script. It is also possible to make it a JSON array to represend your configuration if you have a long list of these.

$(function(){
    $('input[name="ItemGrp1"],input[name="ItemGrp2"]').change(function (e) {

```
    var currentGrp=$(this).attr('name');

    var alreadyChecked=$('input[name="'+currentGrp+'"]:checked').length;
    debugger;
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        alreadyChecked--;

    if(currentGrp=='ItemGrp1'&&alreadyChecked==1&&$(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    else if(currentGrp=='ItemGrp2'&&alreadyChecked==2&&$(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=ItemGrp1]").change(function(){
    if ($("input[name=ItemGrp1]:checked").length >0){
        $("input[name=ItemGrp1]").not(':checked').prop('disabled',true)
    }else{
        $("input[name=ItemGrp1]").prop('disabled',false)}
   });

  $("input[name=ItemGrp2]").change(function(){
    if ($("input[name=ItemGrp2]:checked").length >1){
        $("input[name=ItemGrp2]").not(':checked').prop('disabled',true)
    }else{
        $("input[name=ItemGrp2]").prop('disabled',false)}
   });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K69S2/)**

Answer (score 0):

may be this useful

```
<input class="one" name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="10" />
<input class="one" name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="20" />
<input class="one" name="ItemGrp1" type="checkbox" value="30" />
<input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="40" />
<input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="50" />
<input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="60" />
<input class="two" name="ItemGrp2" type="checkbox" value="70" />
```

below jquery

```
$( ".one" ).on( "change", function() {      
    if(this.checked)
    {
        $(".one").each(function () {
            this.checked=false;            
        });
        this.checked =true;
    }   
});

$( ".two" ).on( "change", function() {   
    if (+$("input[name=ItemGrp2]:checked").length > 2)
    {
        this.checked=false;
    }             
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mA7GE/2/)